# How to sort Response alphabetically in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, sort

Here I wish to sort my **response alphabetical** to the **college names** :

```
   if($collegeid!=null)
                {
                        $res['status']  = true;
                        $res['message'] = "High Priority Students";
                        $res['hpstu']   = $customerData;                   
                }else
                {
                    $collegeData = array();
                    $i = 0;
                    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
                    {
                        $college =Mage::getModel("manager/campus")->load($key);
                        $collegeData[$i]['id'] =$college->getId();
                        $collegeData[$i]['college'] = $college->getName();
                        $collegeData[$i]['hpstudents'] = $value;
                        $i++;
                    }
                }

               $res['page_size'] = $HighPriCollection->getLastPageNumber();                 
               $res['college'] = sort($collegeData); 
               $res['total'] = sizeof($HighPriCollection);

            }
```

Response is coming :

```
{"page_size":1,"college":[{"id":"77","college":"C. University - Linken Road Campus","hpstudents":17},{"id":"537","college":"ASC Engnierring College","hpstudents":5}],"total":22}
```

Desired :
 `[{"id":"537","college":"ASC Engnierring College","hpstudents":5},{"id":"77","college":"C. University - Linken Road Campus","hpstudents":17}]`

Answer (score 1):

```
  $sortcollege = array_column($collegeData, 'college');
                    $sorted = array_multisort($sortcollege, SORT_ASC, $collegeData);
```

This helped me !!